# pytest: parametrize class based tests with fixtures (pytest-django)

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django

I'm trying to parametrize my class tests like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('current_user', ["test_profile_premium", "test_profile_free"], indirect=True)
class TestFeedItemsType:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self, current_user, logged_in_client, dummy_object):
        self.client = logged_in_client
        self.test_profile = current_user
        self.object = dummy_object
```

However, I'm getting the error:

> fixture 'current_user' not found

`test_profile_premium` and `test_profile_free` are both existing, valid fixtures in `conftest.py`. I need all functions (tests) in this class-based suite to run against both `test_profile_premium` and `test_profile_free`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass fixtures as parametrization arguments, see [open issue #349](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349) for details. As a workaround, in your example you can introduce a `current_user` fixture that performs the fixture selection based on the fixture name:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def current_user(request):
    return request.getfixturevalue(request.param)


@pytest.fixture
def test_profile_premium():
    return "premiumfizz"


@pytest.fixture
def test_profile_free():
    return "freefizz"


@pytest.mark.parametrize('current_user', ["test_profile_premium", "test_profile_free"], indirect=True)
class TestFeedItemsType:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self, current_user):
        self.test_profile = current_user

    def test_spam(self):
        assert self.test_profile in ("premiumfizz", "freefizz")

    def test_eggs(self):
        assert self.test_profile in ("premiumfizz", "freefizz")
```

Running this example will yield four tests:

```
test_spam.py::TestFeedItemsType::test_spam[test_profile_premium] PASSED
test_spam.py::TestFeedItemsType::test_spam[test_profile_free] PASSED
test_spam.py::TestFeedItemsType::test_eggs[test_profile_premium] PASSED
test_spam.py::TestFeedItemsType::test_eggs[test_profile_free] PASSED
```

Comment: Thank you. This is *pretty close* to what I ended up doing. I needed to define the `expected` results in the parametrization so I used tuples and then `indirect=["profile"]`.